# Restoring a SQL backup .bak and multiple differential backups

Tags: sql, database, backup

We work with a client who has a SQL database that we got a backup of at first, and they send us differential backups every month. So far what I've had to do each month is completely delete the database, restore it from the original .bak with NORECOVERY, and then restore the differentials one by one each with NORECOVERY. Then when I reach the last differential, I'll make the database live so I can query it with a .sql query

Is it possible to restore all the differentials at once? Doing it one by one is a huge pain, and redoing the whole process every month is even more a pain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's hundreds of utility scripts and articles on this subject eg [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1584/auto-generate-sql-server-restore-script-from-backup-files-in-a-directory/). What have you researched so far?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to restore all the differentials one by one, you have to restore only the latest one.

A differential backup has all the changes since the last `FULL` backup, not from the last `DIFF` backup.

In your example you can restore only the `JCIHistorianDB.bak` with no recovery, then `JCIHistorianDB-Diff_2022-07-13.bak` with recovery.

You would restore one of the others, to see how the database was in that day, but if you always want the latest state of the database, you need only the latest DIFF backup.

And of course as @Stu suggested, you can make this task even more automatical with a script.